# Fetching data from mysql database in high charts

Tags: php, mysql, highcharts

I am trying to pull data from mysql and display on highchart bar graph, but I am not sure where my code is incorrect. The result is a blank page.

The code could not be wrong as I have taken it from the index.html file that highchart provides, but it doesn't work for some reason. Could anyone check and let me knpw where I am making any error?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="js/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<?php
    $host="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $password="";
    $db="isat";
    // Create connection
    $con = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$db) or die("Error Message: <br>". mysqli_error($con));
    $data=array();
    $query= "SELECT standard FROM domainlist";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $data[]=$row['standard'];
    }
?>
<script type="text/javascript">

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
    xAxis: {
       categories: [<?php echo join($data, ','); ?>]
    },
    series: [{
        data: [],
        pointStart: 0,
        pointInterval
    }]
});    $(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Compliance'
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Total fruit consumption'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        reversed: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            stacking: 'normal'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'John',
        data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
    }, {
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
    }, {
        name: 'Joe',
        data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
    }]
});});  </script></head>
<body><div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div></body></html>
```

Comment: Whtever data you fetched from your database is in $data[]. where you used it in your high chart?

Comment: for x axis, the categories fetches the value from the data

Comment: Presumably, it's outputting a blank page. If so, it might be an idea to show us the rendered page. Right click on the page and hit View Page Source. DDLs and sample data for domainlist would also be handy

Comment: Read more about using JS on page load, in short `$(function () {` <- this should be before creating chart, otherwise you will try to create chart before page is ready with all DOM elements. Then copy&paste all of the errors from JS console.